# C function does not take more than n number of arguments

Tags: c

Hi I want to know how I should use system function in c dynamically with 2 parameters.

Here is my code as you can see there is port number 3306, I want to use it as dynamically(like user enter port number) but when I try to add `scanf()` then it gives me error that `strcpy()` function does not take 3 arguments and system function does not take 2 arguments..

```
int main ()
{
   char command[50];

   strcpy( command, "netstat -aon | findstr 3306" );
   system(command);

   return(0);
}
```

For the following code how should I change this if I want to `scanf()` number 3306 and concreate it after `netstat -aon | findstr`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about "*Please write the code for me ...*"

Comment: @alk unfortunately that is not an actual close reason.

Comment: Then you might like to pretend you're dump and vote for closing it because you feel it's "*unclear what is asked*" ;-) @immibis

Answer (score 3):

Read the number and use `snprintf()`:

```
   int port;

   if (scanf("%d", &port) != 1) { /* input error */};

   snprintf( command, sizeof command, "netstat -aon | findstr %d", port );
```

Also, use a standard signature for main()  such as: `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *comm1 = "netstat -aon | findstr ";
    char comm2[50];
    char comms[6];
    scanf("%s", &comms);
    strcpy(comm2, comm1);
    strcat(comm2, comms);
    return 0;
}
```

this is less efficient than @Blue Moon's answer, but the point is, there are many ways to do that.